# swipe views with tabs loading all the framents at the same time

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio, swipe

I created a swipe views with tabs.

The problem is that when the activity is created the three fragments loading at the same time. I set the default fragment to start when the activity open so, the anothers fragment haven't download data from server unleess somebody swipe to this fragment.

This is my activity, I'm not gonna put the code from the three fragments because I think is not relevant for the solution, but if is necessary let me know.

```
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Information extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

String id;
String idUser;
Complejo complejo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_icon_text_tabs);
    recogerParametro();
    setTitle(complejo.getName());


    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_informacion_complejo, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.btn_llamarBarra:
            try {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + complejo.getTelefono().toString()));
                startActivity(callIntent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityException) {
                Log.e("Llamando..", "Falló la llamada", activityException);
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFrag(new GaleriaComplejoFragment(), "GALERÍA");
    adapter.addFrag(new InformacionComplejoFragment(), "INFORMACIÓN");
    adapter.addFrag(new ComentariosComplejoFragment(), "COMENTARIOS");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, false);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}

private void recogerParametro() {
    id= getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
    idUser = getIntent().getStringExtra("idUser");
    complejo = (Complejo) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("complejo");
}
}
```

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: ViewPager functioning: It loads 3 fragment at a time, 1st the default one, second: the left fragment to the default one, third: the right fragment to the default one

Comment: I know that but how can i change the code?

Comment: Put code in onresume in fragments with condition that if data not loaded then only load new data otherwise display already loaded data. Because onresume gets called many times.

Answer (score 0):

As already said, you cannot load a single view/fragment in a ViewPager at any time because the minimum offScreenPageLimit is 1 i.e. a minimum of three fragments will be loaded at a time.

If you want to load your data structure and populate views only when the fragment becomes visible i.e. when swiped, make use of the `setUserVisibleHint()` method of your Fragment -

```
@Override
  public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    if (isVisibleToUser) {
      loadMyStuff();
    }
  }
```

You can also cache the data once you have received it from your server call and check for request only if its null inside `setUserVisibleHint()`

Note that this method will be called each time your Fragment is swiped.

Comment: Thats not the problems. What you said is ok. But the problem is when the activity inicializate, the first fragment start to loading.

Comment: So when exactly do you want to load the fragment data?

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean isLoaded =false,isVisibleToUser;

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
this.isVisibleToUser=isVisibleToUser;
if(isVisibleToUser && isAdded() ){
    loadData();
    isLoaded =true;
 }
}

 @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
if(isVisibleToUser && (!isLoaded)){
    loadData();
    isLoaded=true;
    }
}
```